# How are $\exp(x)$ and $\ln(x)$ originally defined/ found, and in what order were the expansions discovered/ which expansions were primordial?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I always forget how exactly $\exp(x)$ and $\ln(x)$ are defined.  There are obviously a lot of possibilities for circular reasoning (i.e. $\ln(\exp(x)) := x$, but then also $\exp(\ln(x)) := x$).  Their properties, such as $\exp(x) > 0$ for all real numbers, and $\ln(x)$ only being defined on $x > 0$, as well as their derivatives, all are self-referential to some degree thus I just want to understand which order they come from.

As I understand it, $\ln(|x|)$ was originally defined as the antiderivative of $1/|x|$, and then $\exp(x)$ as the inverse?  From there, I believe one can then get all the properties of $\exp$?  But then there seems to be an independent definition of $e$, which is the limit of $(1+1/n)^n$ as $n\to \infty$.  Was it just when this was expanded into an infinite series, it was found to be equal to the power series of $\exp(x)$?

Comment: This might be better on the history of mathematics forum.

Comment: This can be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_logarithms#Natural_logarithm

Comment: See the following freely available 7-part paper: Florian Cajori, *History of the exponential and logarithmic concepts*, **American Mathematical Monthly** 20 #1−7 (January−September 1913),
[pp. 5−14](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2973509), [pp. 35−47](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974078), [pp. 75−84](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2973441), [pp. 107−117](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2972960), [pp. 148−151](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2972412), [pp. 173−182](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2973069), [pp. 205−210](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974104).

Comment: @DanielV It's not a history question though, I just want to know in what order they are defined.  Like it doesn't really matter to me which was defined first, but rather from which fundamental definitions everything stems from.

Comment: There is no such thing as fundamental definitions.

Comment: *but rather from which fundamental definitions everything stems from* --- Since there are many mathematically equivalent ways of doing this, for various individual reasons authors use many different "fundamental definitions" from which to obtain everything else. If you have a university library nearby, a quick browse of books in real analysis on the shelves will clearly show this.